# Tensorflow LSTM not learning for Univariate Time Series binary classification for Imbalanced Dataset

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, time-series, lstm

I have an unbalanced univariate time series data, class 0 instances = 7898, class 1 instances = 1371
I'm using the following LSTM model with ROC-AUC curve plotting and finding optimal threshold for evaluation. But the model is performing worse/only slightly better than random guess. It isn't learning.
Dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/avinemmatty/theft-data

I've applied normalization (0-1) and outlier removal on the dataset.

Here's some of the code I'm using and data preprocessing steps:
I'm applying SMOTE oversampling on the training data, so after SMOTE, I have train, test, val as follows:

```
(CHK_STATE
0.0    5528
1.0    5528
Name: count, dtype: int64,
CHK_STATE
0.0    1185
1.0     205  
Name: count, dtype: int64,  
CHK_STATE  
0.0    1185  
1.0     206  
Name: count, dtype: int64)
```

Here is the code for plotting ROC-AUC curve and getting optimal threshold:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_roc_curve(y_true, y_pred_prob):
    # Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_true, y_pred_prob)
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)

    # Find optimal threshold
    optimal_idx = np.argmax(tpr - fpr)
    optimal_threshold = thresholds[optimal_idx]
    print("Optimal Threshold:", optimal_threshold)

    # Plot the ROC curve
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, color='darkorange', lw=2, label='ROC curve (area = %0.2f)' % roc_auc)
    plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color='navy', lw=2, linestyle='--')
    plt.scatter(fpr[optimal_idx], tpr[optimal_idx], marker='o', color='red', label='Optimal Threshold')
    plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
    plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
    plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
    plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
    plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) Curve')
    plt.legend(loc="lower right")
    plt.show()

    return optimal_threshold
```

Code for LSTM training:

```
def LSTM(X_train, X_test, X_val, y_train, y_test, y_val, class_weights):
    print('LSTM with 1D Convolution:')
    
    model = Sequential()
    
    # Adding 1D Convolutional layers
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=7, activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
    
#     model.add(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=7, activation='relu'))
#     model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
    
    # LSTM layers
    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(64, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(CuDNNLSTM(64))
    
    # Fully connected layers
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    
    early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, restore_best_weights=True)
    lr = 0.0001
    optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)
    print("Learning Rate:", lr)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=optimizer,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    X_train = X_train.to_numpy().reshape((X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
    X_test = X_test.to_numpy().reshape((X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))
    X_val = X_val.to_numpy().reshape((X_val.shape[0], X_val.shape[1], 1))

    print("X_train Shape:", X_train.shape)
    print("X_test Shape:", X_test.shape)
    print("X_val Shape:", X_val.shape)
    print("y_train Shape:", y_train.shape)
    print("y_test Shape:", y_test.shape)
    print("y_val Shape:", y_val.shape)

    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), epochs=200, shuffle=False, batch_size=256, callbacks=[early_stopping])
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
    plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
    plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
    plt.title('Model Loss')
    plt.ylabel('Loss')
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.legend(['Train', 'Validation'], loc='upper right')
    plt.show()

    y_pred_prob = model.predict(X_test)
    # Plot ROC curve for train, val also 
    optimal_threshold = plot_roc_curve(y_test, y_pred_prob)
    prediction = (y_pred_prob > optimal_threshold).astype("int32")
    f1 = results(y_test, prediction)

    return prediction
```

Training output:

```
LSTM with 1D Convolution: Using 0.5 as threshold... 
Learning Rate: 0.0001 
X_train Shape: (11056, 365, 1) 
X_test Shape: (1390, 365, 1) 
X_val Shape: (1391, 365, 1) 
y_train Shape: (11056,) 
y_test Shape: (1390,) 
y_val Shape: (1391,) 
Epoch 1/200 44/44 [==============================] - 6s 45ms/step - loss: 0.8197 - accuracy: 0.4955 - val_loss: 0.6875 - val_accuracy: 0.8519 
Epoch 2/200 44/44 [==============================] - 1s 28ms/step - loss: 0.7627 - accuracy: 0.4974 - val_loss: 0.6878 - val_accuracy: 0.8483 
Epoch 3/200 44/44 [==============================] - 1s 32ms/step - loss: 0.7386 - accuracy: 0.5005 - val_loss: 0.6862 - val_accuracy: 0.8354 
Epoch 4/200 44/44 [==============================] - 1s 28ms/step - loss: 0.7217 - accuracy: 0.5078 - val_loss: 0.6870 - val_accuracy: 0.8224 
Epoch 5/200 44/44 [==============================] - 1s 28ms/step - loss: 0.7156 - accuracy: 0.5078 - val_loss: 0.6869 - val_accuracy: 0.8030 
Epoch 6/200 44/44 [==============================] - 1s 28ms/step - loss: 0.7125 - accuracy: 0.5021 - val_loss: 0.6882 - val_accuracy: 0.7843 
Epoch 7/200 44/44 [==============================] - 1s 28ms/step - loss: 0.7093 - accuracy: 0.4999 - val_loss: 0.6899 - val_accuracy: 0.7132 
Epoch 8/200 44/44 [==============================] - 1s 28ms/step - loss: 0.7062 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.6969 - val_accuracy: 0.3918
```

[image]

Clearly an issue in the learning process
Can anyone suggest any steps I should try?

One thing to note is that if I put shuffle = True in model.fit, then ROC-AUC is coming out much better. Why is this? But I need deterministic results, so I set it to be False.

I think the shapes of the inputs are fine. How do I improve my results? I'm stuck at this point. I tried undersampling too, but that was of no use either. Changing the model architecture or learning rate doesnt help much. In my opinion it should do much better than a random guess.

Classification Report as calculated by sklearn on the test dataset:

```
Accuracy 80.71942446043165
RMSE: 0.4390965217303406
MAE: 0.19280575539568345
F1: [88.97119342 23.42857143]
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

         0.0       0.87      0.91      0.89      1185
         1.0       0.28      0.20      0.23       205

    accuracy                           0.81      1390
   macro avg       0.58      0.56      0.56      1390
weighted avg       0.78      0.81      0.79      1390
```

Comment: We never use `dropout` be default from the beginning - we use it only when we have reasons to suspect possible overfitting (which is the exact opposite of "my model doesn't learn" you report here); but this is not a *programming* question, hence it is actually off-topic here. Please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info